# Input box border not being changed

Tags: html, css

Setting up some validation on a form I have had a look at a number of previous answers and reached the following:

CSS

```
.required_field {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
}
```

When a field is found to be empty/null I am adding the class:

JavaScript

```
$('#new_name').addClass('required_field');
```

I have tested the class on a div and it adds the border correctly but why does it not change the border colour of an `input` box?

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="new_name" name="new_name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I can see that the class is being added but the border is not changing `input box` colour. Why might this be?

ANSWER

It appeared that `Input` already had some CSS rules dictating the format of the input box but I had assuming that adding a class to ovrerwrite these rules would work, which it didn't.

By adding **!important** to the end of each rule in the required_field class (as suggested in the comments) forced the overwrite and consequently the border colour changed as required.

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: Try adding `!important` to your CSS values, should overwrite existing ones.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/5qLgz97g/

Comment: Your code is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/z8s99f1u/ . Try checking in DevTools if you have any higher priority rule applied.

Comment: Seems to be conflict in CSS - thanks

Comment: @RGriffiths - see my answer which used the snippet editor. Alas SO does not allow submit, so I added a [mcve] in JSFiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/akavrx6y/

Comment: @RGriffiths - if your issue is solved by fixing some CSS, please delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Works for if I wrap in $(function() { .. }) and preventDefault:

> Test here: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/akavrx6y/ since SO does not allow submits

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    if ($.trim($('#new_name').val()) == "") {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#new_name').addClass('required_field');
    } else {
      $('#new_name').removeClass('required_field');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.required_field {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="new_name" name="new_name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The add/remove can be written

```
$('#new_name').toggleClass('required_field',$.trim($('#new_name').val()) == "");
```